# WPF Toolkit DataGridCell Style DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, datatrigger

I am trying to change the color of a cell to Yellow if the value has been updated in the DataGrid.

My XAML:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="TheGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False"                             
                  SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" 
                  EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.CellStyle>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

The grid is bound to a List of arrays (displaying a table of values kind of like excel would). Each value in the array is a custom object that contains an IsDirty dependency property. The IsDirty property gets set when the value is changed.

When i run this:

- change a value in column 1 = whole row goes yellow
- change a value in any other column = nothing happens

I want only the changed cell to go yellow no matter what column its in. Do you see anything wrong with my XAML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `DataContext` is set at row level and doesn't change for each `DataGridCell`. So when you bind to `IsDirty` it binds to the property of row-level data object, not cell-level one.

Since your example shows that you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to false, I assume that you generate columns yourself have something like `DataGridTextColumn` with `Binding` property set to binding to actual value field. To get cell style changed to yellow you'd have to change `CellStyle` on each `DataGridColumn` like this:

```
foreach (var column in columns)
{
    var dataColumn =
        new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = column.Caption,
                Binding = new Binding(column.FieldName),
                CellStyle = 
                new Style
                    {
                        TargetType = typeof (DataGridCell),
                        Triggers =
                            {
                                new DataTrigger
                                    {
                                        Binding = new Binding(column.FieldName + ".IsDirty"),
                                        Setters =
                                            {
                                                new Setter
                                                    {
                                                        Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
                                                        Value = Brushes.Yellow,
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            };
    _dataGrid.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
}
```

You can experiment with changing `DataContext` of each cell using `DataGridColumn.CellStyle`. Perhaps only then you'll be able to bind cell's to 'IsDirty' directly from grid-level style like you do without doing it for each column individually. But I don't have actual data model you have to test this.

Comment: Awesome! This worked exactly how I needed it to. The only thing I had to change was adding a Value=true to the DataTrigger(so it triggers when IsDirty is true)

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this but writing my style in xaml? is this possible?

Comment: This is great. However -- I'm trying to do this in WPF, and this appears to be code from the System.Windows.Controls namespace.  Is there a way to do something similar in System.Windows.Forms???  I can't find a resource anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I am in fact using System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid in a plugin that also uses System.Windows.Forms.  The multiple namespaces and using statements are causing some confusion for me.  That said, my Binding class also does not have a constructor that takes only one argument.  What namespace is that in? Also, is "column.FieldName" a stand-in for a custom property on the column?  Thanks.