# WPF individual cell colors in DataGrid using DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF.  The DataGrid is bound to data in a DataTable.  The DataGrid has ItemsSource="{Binding}".  There are no set DataGridTextColumn entries.  The DataTable columns/rows are determined dynamically through database tables.

In the example below the database column names are put into a list and the DataTable is setup so there is a name in the first column and a series of integer values following:

```
DataTable theDataTable= new DataTable();
theDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
for(int i = 0; i < columnNameList.Count ; i++)
    theDataTable.Columns.Add(columnNameList[i], typeof(int));
```

Next the DataGrid is associated (bound) to the DataTable

```
theDataGrid.DataContext = theDataTable;
```

Next the rows are setup in the DataTable.  Again, the number of rows is determined by users in the database.  User names are put into a list after a database call.  Row values are defaulted to zero.

```
for (int i = 0; i < usersNames.Count ; i++)
{
    DataRow newDataRow = theTradersDataTable.NewRow();
    newDataRow["Name"] = usersNames[i];

    for(int j = 0; i < columnNameList.Count ; j++)
    {
        newDataRow[columnNameList[j]] = 0;
    }
    theDataTable.Rows.Add(newDataRow);
 }
```

Following the DataGrid setup, I connect to an API that provides callbacks with user information updates.  Upon the update, I determine the row and column that should be update the underlying DataTable which in turn updates the DataGrid.  This all works just fine.

```
//inside some API callback
theDataTable.Rows[rowNumber][columnNumber] = someDataSentInViaAPI;
```

Finally the question: How do you update a particular cell's color of the DataGrid based on the value in that cell.  Upon callbacks from the API where I receive the data, the cells are updating continuously.  So I'd like to update the color of the cell as the updates come in.

I am not married to my design.  I do not want to make this model fit based on code I've already done.  I am up for most any idea but I would prefer not to hard code column names.  I would also prefer a method that allows me to check a cell's color and then only repaint if necessary (for speed/CPU reasons).  Thank you in advance for all help.

Comment: There seems to be no nice solution to this. So easy in winforms, borderline impossible and horribly ugly in WPF

Comment: I have the same problem, I have to show diferent datatables in a datagrid, and then I need to change color to X number of cells based on a List<X_Y>() where X_Y class, indicate a row an a column in the datagrid. 
I can't find solutions, did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look into data triggers. The following [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2830521/590790) can give you an example.